# Удаление подстрок

Tags: java

Даны 2 строки. Как удалить из 1 все подстроки 2 (если есть)? Спасибо.

Answer (score 7):

```
str1.replaceAll(str2, "");
```

Вы поройтесь в [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) - там много интересного.

Comment: а еще можно регуляркой сплитануть строку 1 строкой 2 и склеить )

Comment: еще можно смотреть список методов, если IDE умеет подсказывать при набранной точке.

Comment: Не-не. Новичкам всегда рекомендуют кодить в блокноте и компилировать из командной строки. А блокнот им ничего не подскажет. Так что остается только JavaDoc напополам с Хорстманом читать.

Comment: Один только огромный минус - String is immutable. А значит каждый раз будет создаваться новая строка.

Comment: в ФП вообще все immutable и никто пока не умер

Comment: Ну, прикольно, что я могу сказать...